# Como somar elementos do servidor

Tags: php, mysql, sistemas-distribuídos

Ola, gostaria de saber como faço para somar valores que me passam do servidor. 
Eu criei um sistema que controla os gastos/contas, você cadastra uma de suas contas.
EX: 

Nome: Carro
Valor: R$ 10.000 (por mês)
Vezes: 5
Total: $valor * vezes.(R$ 50.000)

Nome: Casa
Valor: R$ 20.000 (por mês)
Vezes: 5
Total: $valor * vezes.(R$ 100.000)

---

TOTAL GERAL ...(COMO FAZER ?)

Só que agora eu quero somar o total da primeira 'conta' com o total da segunda 'conta'. Como faço isso ? 
Código:

```
session_start();
 include("includes/conexa.php");
require_once 'init.php';
require 'check.php';
$voce = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
include("includes/topotw.php"); 
echo "$voce e Seu ID: $id";

echo "";
include('includes/conexa.php');
$consulta = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM  `contas`  WHERE id_pessoa LIKE '%".$id."%'");  
    while($linha = $consulta ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
      header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
     Conta: {$linha['nome_conta']}

     Valor: R$ {$linha['valor_conta']}

      Vezes a Pagar:{$linha['vezes_conta']}

      $vl = $linha['valor_conta'];
            $vx = $linha['vezes_conta'];
            $total = $vl * $vx;
            Total:  $total 

    } 


 
?>
```

Comment: Andre Junior, mostra o código

Comment: Ok, vou editar.

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma variável fora do loop e depois dentro do loop vá somando com cada total, e exiba fora do loop:

```
session_start();
 include("includes/conexa.php");
require_once 'init.php';
require 'check.php';
$voce = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$totalGeral = 0;
include("includes/topotw.php"); 
echo "$voce e Seu ID: $id";

echo "";
include('includes/conexa.php');
$consulta = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM  `contas`  WHERE id_pessoa LIKE '%".$id."%'");  
    while($linha = $consulta ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
      header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Conta: 

{$linha['nome_conta']}


Valor: 

R$ {$linha['valor_conta']}


Vezes a Pagar:

{$linha['vezes_conta']}

      $vl = $linha['valor_conta'];
            $vx = $linha['vezes_conta'];
            $total = $vl * $vx;

Total: 

 {$total} 

$totalGeral += $total;

    } 


 TOTAL GERAL: <?php echo $totalGeral;?>
?>
```

Comment: Está "funcionando" só que na primeira aparece o erro "Notice: Undefined variable: totalGeral in /home/u603863053/public_html/sistema_conta/contas.php on line 26
"

Comment: Estranho.. Teria como postar o seu código no pastebin.com ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/V3CRJ1zR